# Unable to submit jobs to spark cluster (cluster-mode)

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Spark version 1.3.0

Error while submitting jobs to spark cluster in cluster mode

```
 ./spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.streaming.JavaDirectKafkaWordCount --deploy-mode cluster wordcount-0.1.jar 172.20.5.174:9092,172.20.9.50:9092,172.20.7.135:9092 log
```

Yields:

```
Spark assembly has been built with Hive, including Datanucleus jars on classpath
Running Spark using the REST application submission protocol.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
15/04/14 16:41:10 INFO StandaloneRestClient: Submitting a request to launch an application in spark://172.20.9.151:7077.
Warning: Master endpoint spark://172.20.9.151:7077 was not a REST server. Falling back to legacy submission gateway instead.
15/04/14 16:41:11 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Sending launch command to spark://172.20.9.151:7077
Error connecting to master spark://172.20.9.151:7077 (akka.tcp://sparkMaster@172.20.9.151:7077), exiting.
```

Answer (score 20):

The Master Spark REST URL is on port 6066 by default.
So you should see this as your Master endpoint: spark://172.20.9.151:6066.

If you go the to Spark web console (http://master:8080) you will get the details of the various endpoints of your cluster.

Comment: Why does it require REST URL? Aren't we supposed to give spark, master URL, the one generally running on port 7077?